# Wordpress plugin conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, position

I have a left and right advertising plugin, but want to show it only to main page (index page)

I have tryed to put a if conditions in plugin but doesn`t work. How to do it correctly?

This is floatads.js file code: http://pastebin.com/qeUHPn08
This is float_left_right_ads.php file code: http://pastebin.com/xm6GxF4d

Thanks for all info and help!

Answer (score 0):

The front page is the main page if you chose it so in the dashboard setting. Inside

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // display your advertisment plugin
}
```

Comment: I`ve tryed to write this condition in flat_left_right_ads.php file before functions mobile show and show in body but after this ads disappeared from all pages.